# Python entry_point in virtual environment not working

Tags: python, package, virtualenv, setuptools, entry-point

I have a virtual environment where I am developing a Python package. The folder tree is the following:

```
working-folder
|-setup.py
|-src
  |-my_package
    |-__init__.py
    |-my_subpackage
      |-__init__.py
      |-main.py
```

`main.py` contains a function `my_main` that ideally, I would want to run as a bash command.

I am using `setuptools` and the `setup` function contains the following line of code

```
setup(
...
    entry_point={
        "console_scripts": [
            "my-command = src.my_package.my_subpackage.main:my_main",
        ]
    },
...
)
```

When I run `pip install .` the package gets correctly installed in the virtual environment. However, when running `my-command` on the shell, the command does not exist.

Am I missing some configuration to correctly generate the entry point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply mistyped the argument `entry_point`, which actually is `entry_points`. Unfortunately, I was not getting any output errors.